# Laravel eloquent hasOne select specific fields

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

Let's assume that I have 2 tables:

**Users:**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('name');
$table->string('email')->unique();
$table->integer('age')
$table->string('password');
$table->rememberToken();
$table->timestamps();
});
```

**Phones:**

```
Schema::create('phones', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
$table->string('phone');
$table->timestamps();

$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
    ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

**User Model:**

```
public function phone()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Phone');
}
```

**Phone Model:**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

When I perform the following query:

```
$result = User::select('name AS full_name', 'email AS user_email', DB::raw("'Student' as 
profile"))->where('age', '>', 10)->with('phone')->get();
```

I get the phone as **null**.

While when performing just:

```
$result = User::where('age', '>', 10)->with('phone')->get();
```

I can get the phone.

Comment: Why do you use `DB::raw("'Student' as profile")`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the user's id, otherwise Laravel cannot match the retrieved phone models with the related user models.

```
$result = User::select(
    'id', // must include keys required for relationships
    'name AS full_name',
    'email AS user_email',
    DB::raw("'Student' as profile")
)
->where('age', '>', 10)
->with('phone')
->get();
```